# Add item in child recycleview from parent recycleview adapter android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on one project which requires to insert an item in child list from parent so,

I'm trying to add an item in child recycle view from parent recycle view adapter.

[image]

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do that by taking array of array . First array for main recycler and child array for child recycler . Now set onClick() for altering items in array and notifydata set changed after that to display data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by Creating 2 `Adapters` Main one will take the main `array` and the second `Adapter` will take the child `array` for example:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"name1",
    "items":
    [
      {"id":2,"name":"name2","valid":true},
      {"id":3,"name":"name3","valid":false},
      {"id":4,"name":"name4","valid":true}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":5,
    "name":"name5",
    "items":
    [
      {"id":6,"name":"name6","valid":true},
      {"id":7,"name":"name7","valid":false}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":8,
    "name":"name8",
    "items":
    [
      {"id":9,"name":"name9","valid":true},
      {"id":10,"name":"name10","valid":false},
      {"id":11,"name":"name11","valid":false},
      {"id":12,"name":"name12","valid":true}
    ]
  }
]
```

When you are setting the sub adapter you will say (items.get(postion).getItems) to be more clear check the code below.

in your main `Adapter` layout add another `RecyclerView` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_category_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_pic"
                android:layout_width="37dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/noimage"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/category_pic"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_arrow"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height=".5dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/secondRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now in your Main `Adapter` you need to initialise your second `Adapter` inside your `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.binding.secondRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        holder.binding.secondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                        if (items.get(position).getChildren() != null) {
                            Sub_Adapter sub_adapter= new Sub_Adapter(items.get(position).getChildren(), context);
                            holder.binding.secondRecyclerView.setAdapter(sub_adapter);
                        }
```

And now all you have to do is to create the second `Adapter` (Sub_Adapter) and inflate different layout if you want or use the same one.